# Как убрать курсор при наведениии на jquery?

Tags: jquery

Как убрать курсор при наведениии на jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам не нужен для этого jQuery. Скрытие курсора делается с помощью CSS:

```
selector {
    cursor: none;
}
```

Comment: @Shad, тогда лучше не просто selector в примере указать, а selector:hover

Comment: $('.language-link.active').css('cursor','default');

Comment: @VenZell, ведь ничего по сути не поменяется. Но, возможно для кого-нибудь действительно будет понятнее.

Comment: js более удобен в таких случаях